# Is the critical inclination the same on every planet in the solar system?

Tags: orbit, thrust, payload, inclination

I am learning about Space exploration.
Is the critical inclination the same on every planet (in the solar system) or does it depend on the planet?

Comment: One question per post, please.

Comment: All good questions. Please edit so there is only one question per post. Otherwise, the "search" function will be hopelessly confused.

Comment: Oh sorry, okay thank you!

Comment: You can post many questions at the same time, as long as they are all separate posts. You have good questions. Bring 'em on !

Comment: Wow THanks for the tip! Will do so ! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Critical inclination **varies between planets**.

According to this paper, https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1108/1108.4639.pdf,

> Most previous researches about the critical inclination were made
> under the assumption that the oblateness term J2 is dominant among the
> harmonic coefficients. This assumption is effective for most large
> celestial bodies, including Earth, Mars, and Moon. However, there
> exist some celestial bodies where the other first few harmonic
> coefficients are of the same order of magnitude as the oblateness term
> J2, or even greater than J2. For example, the J3 and J4 terms of Venus
> are of the same order of magnitude as J2. For these central bodies,
> the concept of the critical inclination is different from that of the
> traditional sense.
>
> … for some cases, the value of the critical inclination is far away
> from that of the traditional sense or even has multiple solutions.

In addition, the critical inclination is sometimes dependent on orbital altitude, as is the case with Jupiter. https://www.mdpi.com/2226-4310/8/7/183

> …  if the eccentricity is small, the critical inclinations will
> decrease as the altitudes of orbits increase; if the eccentricity is
> larger, the critical inclinations will increase as the altitudes of
> orbits increase.

Comment: Thank you very much!